# SQL error in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `password` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `loginkey` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `email` varchar(220) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `postnum` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `awards` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `avatar` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `avatardimensions` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `avatartype` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `usergroup` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `additionalgroups` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `displaygroup` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `usertitle` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `regdate` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `lastactive` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `lastvisit` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `lastpost` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `website` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `icq` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
  `aim` varchar(50) NOT NU[...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>         `password` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
>         `salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFA' at line 3

Basically every time I import this sql file into my database I end up with this error. What causes this error?

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`password` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`loginkey` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`email` varchar(220) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`postnum` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`awards` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`avatar` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`avatardimensions` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`avatartype` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`usergroup` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`additionalgroups` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`displaygroup` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`usertitle` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`regdate` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`lastactive` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`lastvisit` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`lastpost` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`website` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`icq` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`aim` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`yahoo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`msn` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`birthday` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`birthdayprivacy` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'all',
`signature` text NOT NULL,
`allownotices` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`hideemail` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`subscriptionmethod` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`invisible` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`receivepms` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`receivefrombuddy` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`pmnotice` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`pmnotify` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`threadmode` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`showsigs` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`showavatars` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`showquickreply` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`showredirect` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`ppp` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`tpp` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`daysprune` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`dateformat` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`timeformat` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`timezone` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`dst` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`dstcorrection` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`buddylist` text NOT NULL,
`ignorelist` text NOT NULL,
`style` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`away` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`awaydate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`returndate` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`awayreason` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`pmfolders` text NOT NULL,
`notepad` text NOT NULL,
`referrer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`referrals` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`reputation` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`regip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`lastip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`longregip` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`longlastip` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`language` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`timeonline` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`showcodebuttons` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`totalpms` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`unreadpms` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`warningpoints` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`moderateposts` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`moderationtime` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`suspendposting` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`suspensiontime` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`suspendsignature` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`suspendsigtime` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`coppauser` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`classicpostbit` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
`loginattempts` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`usernotes` text NOT NULL,
`newpoints` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`newpoints_items` text NOT NULL,
`passwordconvert` text,
`passwordconverttype` text,
`passwordconvertsalt` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
KEY `usergroup` (`usergroup`),
KEY `birthday` (`birthday`),
KEY `longregip` (`longregip`),
KEY `longlastip` (`longlastip`)
ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=114
)
```

Comment: Please pasteyour create table query fully

Comment: I didn't realize you could just put DEFAULT without a value. What does that do?

Comment: Use `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` if you're going to use `DEFAULT`, otherwise just remove it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6thrq2 I replaced with what you said and got this @Fred-ii-

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hRiDizaT

Comment: still not :( http://prntscr.com/6thvz3

Comment: By the looks of the error you're getting, you **are** doing an `INSERT` or trying to. Why don't you show us where you're using those `'1', 'Der Anarchist', 'some_hashed_password', 'etc'`?

Comment: Show us your `INSERT` statement @Jake

Comment: I have no insert command, it's a sql I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes on your default value, int i made 0 as default value

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `password` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `loginkey` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `email` varchar(220) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `postnum` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `awards` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `avatar` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `avatardimensions` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `avatartype` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `usergroup` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `additionalgroups` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `displaygroup` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `usertitle` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `regdate` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `lastactive` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `lastvisit` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `lastpost` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `website` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `icq` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `aim` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `yahoo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `msn` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `birthday` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `birthdayprivacy` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' 'all',
  `signature` text NOT NULL,
  `allownotices` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `hideemail` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `subscriptionmethod` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `invisible` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `receivepms` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `receivefrombuddy` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `pmnotice` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `pmnotify` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `threadmode` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `showsigs` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `showavatars` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `showquickreply` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0,
  `showredirect` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `ppp` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `tpp` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0 ,
  `daysprune` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `dateformat` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `timeformat` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `timezone` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `dst` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `dstcorrection` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `buddylist` text NOT NULL,
  `ignorelist` text NOT NULL,
  `style` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `away` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0,
  `awaydate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `returndate` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `awayreason` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `pmfolders` text NOT NULL,
  `notepad` text NOT NULL,
  `referrer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `referrals` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `reputation` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `regip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `lastip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `longregip` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0,
  `longlastip` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0 ,
  `language` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `timeonline` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0,
  `showcodebuttons` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' '1',
  `totalpms` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0,
  `unreadpms` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0 ,
  `warningpoints` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `moderateposts` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT  0 ,
  `moderationtime` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `suspendposting` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `suspensiontime` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `suspendsignature` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `suspendsigtime` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `coppauser` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `classicpostbit` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `loginattempts` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '1',
  `usernotes` text NOT NULL,
  `newpoints` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `newpoints_items` text NOT NULL,
  `passwordconvert` text,
  `passwordconverttype` text,
  `passwordconvertsalt` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `usergroup` (`usergroup`),
  KEY `birthday` (`birthday`),
  KEY `longregip` (`longregip`),
  KEY `longlastip` (`longlastip`))
  ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=114
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
      CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ' ,
      `password` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `loginkey` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `email` varchar(220) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `postnum` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `awards` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `avatar` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `avatardimensions` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1x1'
);
```

Set something after DEFAULT keyword or leave without DEFAULT, because they already have a standard default value.
See the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: Column is not null how default value is null ?

Comment: I just tried to demonstrate the correct use of DEFAULT. As I said, instead of NULL, he must place some value. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: I don't see your error, you just repost your code. Apparentily, your error is in this line
 
    ```birthdayprivacy` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' 'all'.```

 Use just '' or just 'all'. You need to choose one default value for each column.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here as mentioned by others is that you are using the keyword `DEFAULT` without providing a default value. I suggest you to either remove the usage of `DEFAULT` or assign a default value for respective columns.

I tried executing the following SQL and it works.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `loginkey` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `postnum` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `awards` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `avatardimensions` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `avatartype` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `additionalgroups` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `displaygroup` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `usertitle` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `regdate` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastactive` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastvisit` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastpost` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `icq` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `aim` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `yahoo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `msn` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `birthdayprivacy` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'all',
  `signature` text NOT NULL,
  `allownotices` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `hideemail` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `subscriptionmethod` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `invisible` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `receivepms` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `receivefrombuddy` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `pmnotice` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `pmnotify` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `threadmode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `showsigs` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `showavatars` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `showquickreply` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `showredirect` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `ppp` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `tpp` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `daysprune` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `dateformat` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `timeformat` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `dst` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `dstcorrection` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `buddylist` text NOT NULL,
  `ignorelist` text NOT NULL,
  `style` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `away` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `awaydate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `returndate` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `awayreason` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pmfolders` text NOT NULL,
  `notepad` text NOT NULL,
  `referrer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `referrals` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `reputation` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `regip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `longregip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `longlastip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `timeonline` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `showcodebuttons` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `totalpms` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `unreadpms` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `warningpoints` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `moderateposts` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `moderationtime` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `suspendposting` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `suspensiontime` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `suspendsignature` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `suspendsigtime` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `coppauser` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `classicpostbit` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `loginattempts` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `usernotes` text NOT NULL,
  `newpoints` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `newpoints_items` text NOT NULL,
  `passwordconvert` text,
  `passwordconverttype` text,
  `passwordconvertsalt` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `usergroup` (`usergroup`),
  KEY `birthday` (`birthday`),
  KEY `longregip` (`longregip`),
  KEY `longlastip` (`longlastip`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=114
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5a3a).

Comment: Are you trying to execute an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: I am trying to import it, and nope just create

Comment: The error seems like it is trying to insert data into the table. Check those values against the columns to be sure.